How to create Flask-Admin view basing on SQLAlchemy models
I Have 2 SQLAlchemy models:
class Topic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'topics'

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = mapped_column(String(50), unique=True)

    **articles = relationship('Article', back_populates='topic')**


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = mapped_column(String(100))
    description = mapped_column(Text)
    views_count = mapped_column(Integer, default=0)
    image = mapped_column(String(200), nullable=True)
    created_at = mapped_column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=func.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
    text = mapped_column(Text)
    foreign_link = mapped_column(Text, nullable=True)

    topic_id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey('topics.id'))

    **topic = relationship('Topic', back_populates='articles')**


That are connected with back_populates relationship.
When I try to create a particular ArticleView to populate topic field on Flask-Admin panel in such a way:
class ArticleView(ModelView):
    form_columns = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'views_count',
        'image',
        'created_at',
        'text',
        'foreign_link',
        'topic',
    ]

I got this kind of error:
...wtforms\widgets\core.py", line 365, in call
for val, label, selected, render_kw in field.iter_choices():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
What is the root reason of it and how can it be fixed?

Try to downgrade WTForms version to 2.3.3

this might be a similar issue: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/25622
